# How do we interpret and perform integrals using infinitesimals?

Tags: integration, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

If $\mathrm{d}x$ is treated as a [hyperreal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) infinitesimal we can easily do derivations.

> How do we interpret and perform integrals using infinitesimals?
>
> What is the $\mathrm{d}x$ in $\int x^3\,\mathrm{d}x$ ?

Comment: I think doing derivatives with infinitesimals is no easier (and if you have the experience, no harder) than with the usual methods.

Comment: You don't. Integration is, courtesy of FTC, purely algorithmic and shouldn't involve infinitesimals. The usual $dx$ before the equals on the LHS is therefore a bit misleading. In this answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833867/visualization-of-surface-area-of-a-sphere/1833935#1833935) a $dx$ naturally appears but the technique is not as good as the alternative - where is doesn't. NB I'm really talking about nilsquare infinitesimals, not hyperreal ones.

Comment: In what I've seen, $\mathrm{d}x$ holds the same meaning as it does in the standard sense; it's just a formal thing, or a differential form if you know about those. That said, I wouldn't be surprised if there was another formulation of differential geometry where $\mathrm{d}x$ was genuinely an infinitesimal-valued thing.

Comment: @user301988 what are you talking about?  Integration is its own thing defined separately from the derivative.  Just as the derivative is a quotient of infinitesimal differences, the integral is an infinite sum of products.  To find an area you take the infinite sum of all the rectangles of height y=f(x) and width dx (infinitesimal) between the bounds of integration, and then round off to the nearest real number to eliminate the infinitesimal error term.

The FTC is a theorem that lets you find an exact integral by means of anti-derivatives instead of needing to numerically approximate them.

Answer (score 11):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\st}{st}$I will explain one way to treat your definite integral in the [Internal Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set_theory) (IST) approach to [Nonstandard Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) (NSA). Before beginning, please be aware this NSA approach is entirely analogous to a classical integral with Riemann sums (whereas NSA topics like continuity are a bit more novel). However, it does allow us to interpret the integral as an actual sum using infinitesimals. I will try to give a *basic idea* how this works in IST.

---

**Very Basic Overview of IST Terminology**

The basic idea of the IST approach is you add 3 axioms and the unary predicate *standard* to [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) to form a conservative extension of ZFC that lets you use infinitesimals and "infinite" numbers in e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual definition. Every set is either *standard* or *not standard*. If you can uniquely define a set with ZFC alone, you can be assured it is standard. Nonzero infinitesimals are, e.g., not standard.

In this approach, it's a conflation of terminology to refer to the "infinite" elements of $\mathbb{R}$ as infinite since they are in fact finite in the set-size sense of the term. Instead, I will use the terms *limited* and *unlimited*.

Finally, you should have a basic idea what the standard part function does. If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is limited, the standard part function, $\st(x)$, is well defined and returns the unique standard number in $\mathbb{R}$ that differs from $x$ by no more than an infinitesimal.

---

We will now use our terminology to interpret the following standard integral (in particular, $t^3$ is a standard function and $x$ is a fixed standard number).

$$\int_0^x t^3\,\mathrm{d}t$$

You may have seen a definite integral defined as the limit of a Riemann sum as the number of rectangles goes to infinity where $x/n$ is the width of the rectangle and $n$ is the number of rectangles:

$$\int_0^x t^3\,\mathrm{d}t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(k\frac{x}{n}\right)^3\frac{x}{n}$$

If we wrote this with the width of the interval, $x/n$, as $h$, we could instead write

$$\int_0^x t^3\,\mathrm{d}t=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\sum_{0\leq kh<x} (kh)^3h$$

However, in NSA, we can just choose a fixed infinitesimal $h>0$ that you might be excused to identify with $\mathrm{d}t$. Provided the integral exists, the result will be no more than an infinitesimal away from the integral, so we can take the standard part to evaluate it.

$$\int_0^x t^3\,\mathrm{d}t=\st\sum_{0\leq kh<x} (kh)^3h$$

Instead of picking an infinitesimal $h$, we could just as easily have picked an unlimited $n$ in the first Riemann sum formula and taken the standard part just the same (this is identifying the arbitrary infinitesimal $h$ you choose with $x/n$ for an unlimited $n$). Let's do this. Fix an unlimited $n$:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^x t^3\,\mathrm{d}t&=
\st \sum_{k=1}^n \left(k\frac{x}{n}\right)^3\frac{x}{n} \\
&=\st\bigg(\frac{x^4}{4}+\underbrace{\frac{x^4}{2n}+\frac{x^4}{4n^2}}_{\substack{\text{infinitesimal}\\ \text{($x$ is standard} \\ \text{$\implies x$ limited)}}}\bigg) \\
&=\frac{x^4}{4}
\end{align*}

---

More generally, the axioms of IST let us prove that for an infinitesimal $h>0$ and standard integral, the following holds:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\st\sum_{a\leq kh<b} f(kh)\,h$$

If you wish to motivate the usual integral notation (though I prefer the above form for lack of ambiguity), we can define $x_k=kh$ and label our infinitesimal $\mathrm{d}x=h$ to get:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\st\sum_{a\leq x_k<b} f(x_k)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

IST works with *real numbers* (modulo certain modifications of the background set theory) rather than the *hyperreal numbers* mentioned in the question.

In the hyperreal setting, one chooses an infinitesimal $dx$ for example as $\frac{b-a}{H}$ where $[a,b]$ is the interval of integration and $H$ is a fixed infinite hypernatural number: $H\in {}^\ast\mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$. Then one partitions the interval $[a,b]$ into $H$ subintervals with partition points $x_i$ as $i$ runs from $0$ to $H$. One forms an infinite Riemann sum by summing the infinitely thin rectangles of width $dx$ and height $f(x_i)$. This is not quite the integral.  To obtain the integral one takes the [standard part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function) of the infinite Riemann sum.

This is similar to the procedure for differentiation mentioned in the question: the last step is an application of standard part.